# Extracting numbers using substring

Tags: javascript, substring, substr

I have a document where I would like to extract specific numbers from a large list.

I can't list the whole code here, and for the sake of simplicity I will show an example, as the code is not necessary.

for example, say I have a list which appears as below:

```
1: text,
2: more text,
3: etc
```

it would be easy to use substring to capture only the first letter in the string, which would be the number I am after. however, what happens when it gets to 10, or 100? keep in mind that I can't change the format or content of the list at all, I can only receive the values in it.

is there a way to get just the number, without the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a regex.

something like

```
var matches = "121: test".match(/^(\d*):\s/)
var val;

if (matches && matches.length > 0) val = matches[1]
```

This regex has a bunch of things you might or might not need

`^`    means the beginning of the line
`()`   means capture this group
`\d*`     means as many digits as you find in a row
`:` is the colon you have in your example
`\s` is the single whitespace character after the colon, in your example

Since we define (\d*), the match method will capture that part of the match (the digits) and make it available in the array.

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you for the extra effort with the [1] at the end, it ensures that I find only on the first number so that I don't get any other numbers that come later. I think it's supposed to be a 0 though, unless I got your intention wrong, in any case, I got something to work from it

Comment: No, the first item int he array (index 0) is the ENTIRE MATCH, which is more then just the number (it has the `:` and the whitespace)

Comment: ah, I see that now, I was using just /\d+/ig. Thanks for your help, regex's are something I want to learn more about, and you've explained it very well.

Answer (score 2):

you ca do substring until indexof(":");
sample code:

```
var str="100: Hello world!";
document.write(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(":")));
```

you get 100 as a result.
Hope this helps! good luck,

Comment: This is a good solution, but the first entry unfortunately had a { at the beginning. thanks for the answer anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Reguler Expressions:

```
var s = "1: text,\n"+
"2: more text,\n"+
"3: etc\n​​"​;

var matches = s.match( /\d+/ig);

for(var i=0;i<matches.length;++i){
   console.log(matches[i]);           
}​​​​​​​​​​
```

see [it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/felice_pollano/4eCSs/).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use regex for this?

```
'100: asds'.replace(/^(\d+):.+$/, '$1'); // 100
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the position of the ':' and then do string.substring(0, position)

```
var str="1000: this is a string";
var number = str.substring(0,str.search(':')); // 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
// limit split to 1 to avoid unnecessary splits
var num = "1000: rest of string".split(":", 1)[0];
```

I ran some test on the methods given here on jsPerf and results [here](http://jsperf.com/split-string)

The fastest method of retrieving the required number is

```
"1000: rest of string".substring(0, str.indexOf(":"));
```

If speed matters then the correct answer should go to user coder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a regex expression would be a better choice for you, but if you needed to use the upper suggested solution, you may do the following to get rid of the "{"

```
if(str.contains("{"))
{
     str.replace("{", "");
}
```